# Ramsey theory, generalized

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Is there a "generalized" Ramsey theory? How large must a graph be such that, with arbitrary connections between vertices, the existence of arbitrarily defined subgraphs is assured?

Comment: This online course from MIT covers questions about graph sizes containing sub graphs. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-217-graph-theory-and-additive-combinatorics-fall-2019/

Answer (score 1):

The paper below rigorously states in the abstract a generalization of Ramsey's Theorem for finding monochromatic subgraphs (not necessarily subcliques/complete graphs) when coloring some arbitrary initial graph.

[http://math.mit.edu/~fox/paper-Ramseymultiplecolors.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/%7Efox/paper-Ramseymultiplecolors.pdf)

This seems like a difficult question and a difficult area of research and I don't currently know of any other papers on this topic. I expect that any arbitrary starting graph (a graph with 'arbitrary connections between the vertices') is too wild to study and obtain any reasonable results. I expect that some conditions such as bipartite, postive density of edges, or regularity will be needed in order to make any reasonable progress on the type of question that you are interested in.